# Outlook do not trusts sender

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

My Outlook 2021 Pro application blocks emails that comes from my colleague from particular domain. E-mail contains two png's that are company logo. Mail is moved to Spam. Trying to tell Outlook it is not junk from context menu
[image]

And next menu should make trust current sender

[image]

But this not happens. Mail appears in Inbox for some time and then gets back to Spam. Next mail from the same sender gets to Spam too. Why Outlook not trusts defined sender? Why Outlook decides it is spam?

Comment: You have selected the "Never Block Sender" option I presume?

Comment: @Ramhound I have selected "Not Junk". It is not enough ?

Comment: Is this account a part of a corporate Exchange environment? Have you talked to somebody about whitelisting this colleague's domain for you?

Comment: I'm not using Exchange at all. It is just simple e-mail message. "Not Junk" and "Never Block Sender" not helped

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete and re-add email addresses that are set in the safe senders list to see if the same issue occurs.
2. Check your blocked senders list. If you accidentally add an email address to your blocked senders list, your safe senders list may be overwritten. For more information, see [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/safe-sender-list-in-outlook-not-working/57252cb3-5404-4088-a3e0-d45f71a4ad7d).

Comment: "Delete and re-add" not helped and there is nothing in block senders list